# Quadratic/Bilinear form positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, symmetric-matrices

I've the following interesting (or that's what I think at least!) question. Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$. I'm interested in the sign of following operation
$$ x^{T} BAC x$$
with $x\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$. Further assumptions:

- The symmetric part of $A$ is positive definite, i.e. $(A+A^T)/2 > 0$
- $B$ is full (row) rank
- $C$ is full (column) rank

**Edit:** I've changed the question as per the useful first comment.

Here comes the question: Is there any relatively "straightforward" additional condition on $B$ and $C$ to guarantee that $x^{T}BACx > 0$ under the hypotheses stated above? (of course I'm not interested in $B=C$).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Presumably there's some underlying reason that you're interested this.  Perhaps asking that more general question would result in a more helpful answer than "no."

Answer (score 1):

No.  Suppose $x^{T}BACx$ is a positive definite quadratic form.  Then $x^{T}BA(-C)x$ is a negative definite quadratic form and $-C$ satisfies the same requirements as $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Ok, a perfect counterexample. Maybe I could rephrase the question: Is there any relatively "straightforward" condition on $B$ and $C$ to say something about $x^{T}BACx$ in terms of $x^{T}Ax$? (of course I'm not interested in $B=C$).

Comment: Question edited! Thanks a million